# Using the universal property of the Tensor Product to show isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I've been given a statement of the universal property of Tensor products that is as follows:

For all $A$-modules $Q$, the homomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M\otimes_A N,Q)\rightarrow \operatorname{Bil}_A(M\times N,Q)$ that sends $f\mapsto f\circ \otimes$ is an isomorphism.

I want to use this to show that a particular $\mathbb{Z}$-module $Q$ is isomorphic to a tensor product $A\otimes \mathbb{Q}$. I have managed to define a Bilinear map $B:A\times\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow Q$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I would really appreciate any guidance you would be able to provide as I was unable to find any nice examples for this kind of problem online.

Comment: What is $f\circ\otimes$?

Comment: $\otimes$ is the map $\otimes:M\times N\mapsto M\otimes_A N$, $f$ is some element of $Hom_A(M\otimes_A N,Q)$

Comment: You need to show first, that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map $A \times \mathbb{Q} \to Q$, which we will call $\otimes$. Then show that for *any* bilinear map $g: A \times \mathbb{Q} \to M$ to an arbitrary abelian group $M$, there is a unique linear map $f: Q \to M$ such that $g=f \circ \otimes$. Do you see why this implies $Q \cong A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Honestly I'm still not sure how that implies $Q\cong A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: How is this particular $Q$ defined?

Comment: If you can show what @leibnewtz suggested, then putting $M = A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ gives you a uniquely defined map $Q \to A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. The universal property for $A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ also gives you a uniquely defined map $A \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to Q$, and you can show that they are inverses.